# Change bar chart axis scale using Aspose.Cells for C#

Tags: c#, excel, aspose-cells

I'm trying to set the axis scale for a bar chart using Aspose.Cells for C#. What I'm currently doing is essentially this:

```
var chart = worksheet.Charts.Add(ChartType.BarChart, 1, 1, 15, 15)
chart.NSeries.AddSeries("{.015,.03,.04}", true)
chart.NSeries.CategoryData = "{Apples,Oranges,Pears}"
chart.SeriesAxis.IsAutomaticMajorUnit = false;
chart.SeriesAxis.MajorUnit = .01;
```

However, when the spreadsheet renders the chart's major unit scale is automatically set to .1, so all the bars look disproportionately small. How can I change the scale of the series axis, so it has tick marks spaced apart by .01?

Comment: I've never used C# or aspose before but it looks like your answer is in the documentation: https://apireference.aspose.com/net/cells/aspose.cells.charts/axis/properties/majorunit (try copy-and-pasting your question title into Google)

Comment: Every day I'm using methods and libraries that I've never used before.  Did you try my other suggestion?  There are various examples from those who have used this particular library. Another suggestion, try you data and same settings in Excel manually. Perhaps there is a reason that major unit is not available, which will become more clear in Excel.

Comment: I don't believe that you've tried my suggestions, but it doesn't matter. "Effective Googling" is a skill that not everyone has. It looks to me like your code matches neither the syntax specified in the documentation, nor in various [examples](https://documentation.devexpress.com/corelibraries/DevExpress.Spreadsheet.Charts.Axis.MajorUnit.property) showing the property in use.... but  don't bother since you're obviously much more knowledgeable than I.  Please forgive me for disrespecting you with my time and effort.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code for your needs.

**C#**

```
//Set the major unit to 0.01
ch.ValueAxis.IsAutomaticMajorUnit = false;
ch.ValueAxis.MajorUnit = 0.01;
```

Here is the full sample code and the screenshot showing the output Excel file generated by the code for your reference.

[image: Set the Chart Axis Major Unit to 0.01 using Aspose.Cells APIs]

**C#**

```
// Create empty workbook.
Workbook wb = new Workbook();

// Access first worksheet.
Worksheet worksheet = wb.Worksheets[0];

// Add Bar chart in first worksheet.
int idx = worksheet.Charts.Add(ChartType.Bar, 5, 2, 20, 10);

// Access Bar chart.
Chart ch = worksheet.Charts[0];

// Add two number series, true means they are vertical.
ch.NSeries.Add("{.015,.03,.04}", true);

// Set the category data to show on X-axis.
ch.NSeries.CategoryData = "{Apples,Oranges,Pears}";

// Set the name of first and second series.
ch.NSeries[0].Name = "Cricket";

//Set the major unit to 0.01
ch.ValueAxis.IsAutomaticMajorUnit = false;
ch.ValueAxis.MajorUnit = 0.01;

// Save the output in xlsx format.
wb.Save("outputBarChart.xlsx", SaveFormat.Xlsx);
```

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose